# C#, EF & LINQ : slow at inserting large (7Mb) records into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, latency

There's a long version of this question, and a short version.

***The short version:***

why are both LINQ and EF so slow at inserting a single, large (7 Mb) record into a remote SQL Server database ?

**And here's the long version**  (with some information about workarounds, which might be useful to other readers):

All of the following example code *does* run okay, but as my users are in Europe and our Data Centers are based in America, it is damned slow.  But if I run the same code on a Virtual PC in America, it runs instantly.  (And no, sadly my company wants to keep all data in-house, so I can't use Azure, Amazon Cloud Services, etc)

Quite a few of my corporate apps involve reading/writing data from Excel into SQL Server, and often, we'll want to save a raw-copy of the Excel file in a SQL Server table.

This is very straightforward to do, simply reading in the raw data from a local file, and saving it into a record.

```
private int SaveFileToSQLServer(string filename)
{
    //  Read in an Excel file, and store it in a SQL Server [External_File] record.
    //
    //  Returns the ID of the [External_File] record which was added.
    //

    DateTime lastModifed = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(filename);
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

    //  Create a new SQL Server database record, containing our file's raw data 
    //  (Note: the table has an IDENTITY Primary-Key, so will generate a ExtFile_ID for us.)
    External_File newFile = new External_File()
    {
        ExtFile_Filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename),
        ExtFile_Data = fileData,
        ExtFile_Last_Modified = lastModifed,
        Update_By = "mike",
        Update_Time = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
    dc.External_Files.InsertOnSubmit(newFile);
    dc.SubmitChanges(); 

    return newFile.ExtFile_ID;
}
```

Yup, no surprises there, and it works fine.

But, what I noticed is that for large Excel files (7-8Mb), this code to insert one (large!) record would take 40-50 seconds to run.  I put this in a background thread, and it all worked fine, but, of course, if the user quit my application, this process would get killed off, which would cause problems.

As a test, I tried to replace this function with code to do this:

- copy the file into a shared directory on the SQL Server machine
- called a stored procedure to read the raw data (blob) into the same table

Using this method, the entire process would take just 3-4 seconds.

If you're interested, here's the Stored Procedure I used to upload a file (which MUST be stored in a folder on the SQL Server machine itself) into a database record:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UploadFileToDatabase]
    @LocalFilename nvarchar(400)
AS
BEGIN
    --  By far, the quickest way to do this is to copy the file onto the SQL Server machine, then call this stored
    --  procedure to read the raw data into a [External_File] record, and link it to the Pricing Account record.
    --
    --      EXEC [dbo].[UploadPricingToolFile] 'D:\ImportData\SomeExcelFile.xlsm'
    -- 
    --  Returns: -1 if something went wrong  (eg file didn't exist) or the ID of our new [External_File] record
    --
    --  Note that the INSERT will go wrong, if the user doesn't have "bulkadmin" rights.
    --      "You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement."
    --  EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'GPP_SRV', @rolename = N'bulkadmin'
    --
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
        @filename nvarchar(300),        --  eg "SomeFilename.xlsx"  (without the path)
        @SQL nvarchar(2000),
        @New_ExtFile_ID int

    --  Extract (just) the filename from our Path+Filename parameter
    SET @filename = RIGHT(@LocalFilename,charindex('\',reverse(@LocalFilename))-1)

    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO [External_File]  ([ExtFile_Filename], [ExtFile_Data]) '
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT ''' + @Filename + ''', * 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @LocalFilename +''', SINGLE_BLOB) rs'

    PRINT convert(nvarchar, GetDate(), 108) + ' Running: ' + @SQL
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC (@SQL)
        SELECT @New_ExtFile_ID = @@IDENTITY
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT convert(nvarchar, GetDate(), 108) + ' An exception occurred.'
        SELECT -1
        RETURN
    END CATCH

    PRINT convert(nvarchar, GetDate(), 108) + ' Finished.'

    --  Return the ID of our new [External_File] record
    SELECT @New_ExtFile_ID
END
```

The key to this code is that it builds up a SQL command like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO [External_File]  ([ExtFile_Filename], [ExtFile_Data])
SELECT 'SomeFilename.xlsm', * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\ImportData\SomeExcelFile.xlsm', SINGLE_BLOB) rs
```

.. and, as both the database and file to be uploaded are both on the same machine, this runs almost instantly.

As I said, overall, it took 3-4 seconds to copy the file to a folder on the SQL Server machine, and run this stored procedure, compared to 40-50 seconds to do the same using C# code with LINQ or EF.

**Exporting blob data from SQL Server into an external file**

And, of course, the same is true in the opposite direction.

First, I wrote some C#/LINQ code to load the one (7Mb !) database record and write its binary data into a raw-file.  This took about 30-40 seconds to run.

But if I exported the SQL Server data to a file (saved on the SQL Server machine) first..

```sql
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "select ef.ExtFile_Data FROM [External_File] ef where ExtFile_ID = 585" queryout "D:\ImportData\SomeExcelFile.xslx" -T -N'
```

...and then copied the file from the SQL Server folder to the user's folder, then once again, it ran in a couple of seconds.

And this is my question: Why are both LINQ and EF so bad at inserting a single large record into the database ?

I assume the latency (distance between us, here in Europe, and our Data Centers in the States) are a major cause of the delay, but it's just odd that a bog-standard file-copy can be so much faster.

Am I missing something ?

Obviously, I've found walkarounds to these problems, but they involve added some extra permissions to our SQL Server machines and shared folders on SQL Server machines, and our DBAs really don't like granting rights for things like "`xp_cmdshell`"...

**A few months later...**

I had the same issue again this week, and tried Kevin H's suggestion to use Bulk-Insert to insert a large (6Mb) record into SQL Server.

Using bulk-insert, it took around 90 seconds to insert the 6Mb record, even though our data centre is 6,000 miles away.

So, the moral of the story: when inserting very-large database records, avoid using a regular `SubmitChanges()` command, and stick to using bulk-insert.

Comment: Don't insert 7mb files into SQL server...

Comment: Umm... You're uploading 7MB to the remote server. That could be your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I know having records containing 7Mb of data is far from ideal...  But my point is, SQL Server provides the blob data type for this exact scenario, LINQ/EF happily support this type, but their performance is lousy... and my question is: *why* is performance so bad..?   Why would writing a single record take 20 times longer than just copying a file to the server ?  Why is latency such an issue, using LINQ/EF ?

Comment: Have you tried disable track changes? EF might be tracking changing on the blob object and that could make it slower. On the other hand, have you tried creating a table that only contains the blob type column and a reference to its parent table?

Comment: @Francisco: Very good idea, suggesting setting ObjectTrackingEnabled to false, but it made no difference in performance.  And my table *does* just contain the blob field and 3 or 4 other fields.. no extra indexes, foreign keys etc...   The issue seems purely down to latency, rather than database structure.

Comment: Have you tried to call the Stored Procedure using EF? I have some queries (same SQL code) that works 3 or 4 times faster when calling the SP from EF than using EF, even without tracking changes.

Comment: This isn't even close to an apples-to-apples comparison. On one hand with the LINQ/EF stuff, you're using a client-side object-based framework to buffer and insert raw data....who knows what's really going on there. On the other hand with the SP, you're using a highly-efficient BULK operation to insert raw data in one go. I'm not surprised at all by the difference in performance.

Comment: I kind of disagree.  In my example, I am uploading the raw data from the same 7Mb Excel file into the same database table on a remote server, using exactly the same hardware and network.  And my question is, why is it 20 times faster to do it one way, rather than the other ?   I would've expected some extra latency, using EF/LINQ, but surely not that much...  If I was comparing a bulk-insert of lots of rows, then yes, but for inserting one (big) record, it just surprises me, that's all...

Comment: It has to do with the difference between streaming data to the database (quick) vs. loading them in memory first and then writing them as a regular insert statement. See [this](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/using-sqlfilestream-in-c-to-access-sql-server-filestream-data/). EF/LINQ-to-SQL don't support this.

Comment: @MikeGledhill your recent edit says that Bulk Insert took 90 seconds which is longer than your original statement of EF taking 30-40 seconds.  Can you clarify your statement?

Comment: @KevinH: You're right, that was misleading.  Suffice to say, bulk-inserts are fast, but getting your C# code to copy the file onto the SQL Server machine, then calling a Stored Procedure to upload it into the database was (by far) the fastest solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using profiler to see what Entity Framework is doing with the insert.  For example, if it's selecting data out of your table, it could be taking a long time to return the data over the wire, and you may not notice that locally.

I have found that the best way to load a large amount of data (both record count and record size) into sql server from c# is to use the [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  Even though you are inserting only 1 record, you may still benefit from this change.

To use bulk copy, just create a datatable that matches the structure of your table. Then call the code like this.

```
using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new    SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "External_File";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}
```

Comment: Damn.  You're absolutely right.  Ironically, in the past I've actually documented how to do this for bulk-inserting *lots* of rows, but I didn't realise that it was just as useful for inserting a huge record aswell.   Great tip, thanks !   http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/LINQ/InsertAndDeletes.htm